# Infinite carousel animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a spinner like loader but in my own style, this is like a carousel like it spins horizontally infinitely and add 'active' class to the item that caught inside the search icon but it seems my code does not produce the right result. I just want to loop it like a carousel infinitely and add class to the item that is inside the search icon, any help, ideas please?

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    animateSpinner();
  }, 2000);
});

function animateSpinner() {
  $('.anim-wrapper').animate({
    left: -(parseInt($('.anim-wrapper').attr('data-start-offset')) + 60)
  }, 500, function() {
    $('.anim-wrapper .active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    $('.anim-circle:nth-child(1)').appendTo($('.anim-wrapper'));
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 64px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #242424;
}

.anim-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  left: -14px;
  position: relative;
  width: 720px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 61px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.anim-circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ededed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.magnifying-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0px auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 100px;
  top: 11px;
}

.cn-spinner {
  width: 295px;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.anim-circle.active {
  /* transform: scale(1.21); */
  background: #ef7100;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://1662037994.rsc.cdn77.org/plugins/foundry/css/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position-relative cn-spinner center-content-parent">
  <div class="magnifying-wrapper">
    <i class="ti-search"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="anim-wrapper overflow-auto" data-start-offset="14">
    <li class="anim-circle">Jobs</li>
    <li class="anim-circle">Real<br>estate</li>
    <li class="anim-circle active">Busi-<br>ness</li>
    <li class="anim-circle">Cars</li>
    <li class="anim-circle">Deals</li>
    <li class="anim-circle">Events</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working demo with your code.i adjusted the left value to handle it as per your requirement.

```js
$(function(){

   setInterval(function(){
    animateSpinner();
   }, 2000);
  });

  function animateSpinner(){
   $('.anim-wrapper').animate({
    left: -  ( parseInt( $('.anim-wrapper').attr('data-start-offset') ) )
    },
    500, function() {

    $('.anim-wrapper .active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    $('.anim-circle:nth-child(1)').appendTo($('.anim-wrapper'));
    

   });
  }
```

```css
body{
   padding: 64px;
   margin: 0px;
   color: #242424;
  }
  .anim-wrapper{
    overflow: auto;
   left: -14px;
      position: relative;
         width: 720px;
         padding:  0px;
         margin: 0px;
      top: 10px;
      height: 61px;
      overflow:hidden;
  }
  .anim-circle{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background:#ededed;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 5px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   font-size: 12px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .position-relative{
   position: relative;
  }
  .magnifying-wrapper{
   position: absolute;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      z-index: 999;
      margin: 0px auto;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: 100px;
      top: 11px;
  }
  .cn-spinner{
   width: 295px;
      position: relative;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  .anim-circle.active{
   /* transform: scale(1.21); */
   background: #ef7100;
   color: #FFF;
 animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  }
@keyframes spin {
from {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
}
to {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://1662037994.rsc.cdn77.org/plugins/foundry/css/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position-relative cn-spinner center-content-parent">
  <div class="magnifying-wrapper">
   <i class="ti-search"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="anim-wrapper overflow-auto" data-start-offset="14">
   
   <li class="anim-circle">Jobs</li>
   <li class="anim-circle">Real<br>estate</li>
   <li class="anim-circle active">Busi-<br>ness</li>
   <li class="anim-circle">Cars</li>
   <li class="anim-circle">Deals</li>
   <li class="anim-circle">Events</li>

  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach it looks like the animation is only run once, even though it does run as expected.
The reason is that on your first animation you set it to -74 (60 +14 offset), but you never change this value which is why it remains at -74. 
The jumpy "animation" is what it looks like when you remove and append elements.

I've put together a quick'n dirty solution which might need a bit of tweeking.

This manipulates the first child within .anim-wrapper, rather than the element itself.

```js
    
    $(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        $('.anim-circle:nth-child(1)').animate({
          marginLeft: -74
        }, 500, function() {
          $('.anim-circle:nth-child(1)').css('margin-left', 5);
          $('.anim-wrapper .active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
          $('.anim-circle:nth-child(1)').appendTo($('.anim-wrapper'));
        });
      }, 2000);
    });
```

```css
    
      body {
      padding: 64px;
      margin: 0px;
      color: #242424;
    }
    
    .anim-wrapper {
      overflow: auto;
      left: -14px;
      position: relative;
      width: 720px;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      top: 10px;
      height: 61px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    
    .anim-circle {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: #ededed;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 5px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .position-relative {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .magnifying-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      z-index: 999;
      margin: 0px auto;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: 100px;
      top: 11px;
    }
    
    .cn-spinner {
      width: 295px;
      position: relative;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .anim-circle.active {
      background: #ef7100;
      color: #FFF;
    }
```

```html
    
        <link href="https://1662037994.rsc.cdn77.org/plugins/foundry/css/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position-relative cn-spinner center-content-parent">
  <div class="magnifying-wrapper">
    <i class="ti-search"></i>
  </div>

  <ul class="anim-wrapper data-start-offset="14">
    <li class="anim-circle">Jobs</li>
    <li class="anim-circle">Real<br>estate</li>
    <li class="anim-circle active">Busi-<br>ness</li>
    <li class="anim-circle">Cars</li>
    <li class="anim-circle">Deals</li>
    <li class="anim-circle">Events</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```